# Spring JPA combine queries each with different sort

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity:

```java
@Entity(name = "Product")
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private UUID id;

  private String barcode;

  private String description;

  // ... Additional fields removed for clarity

  @Min(0)
  private Integer quantity;
  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

  @Column(insertable = false)
  private ZonedDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

and I have been scratching my head on how to using Spring data JPA, in particular `PagingAndSortingRepository` so that I can return pageable products where those products where `quantity > 0` are returned first, and those where `quantity = 0` or `quantity is NULL` are returned last. So it's like there are two groups, one with `quantity > 0` and the other one with `quantity = 0` or `quantity is NULL`. Another constraint is that for each group, the products need to be sorted by `updatedAt` field in descending order.

With SQL query, the following achieves what I need:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM product WHERE quantity > 0 
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM product WHERE quantity = 0 OR quantity IS NULL
) s 
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN quantity > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, 
  updated_at DESC;
```

But when I wrote it to my repository class, as show below:

```java
  @Query(
      "SELECT p FROM ("
          + "  SELECT a FROM product a WHERE a.quantity > 0 "
          + "  UNION "
          + "  SELECT b FROM product b WHERE b.quantity = 0 OR b.quantity IS NULL "
          + ") p "
          + "ORDER BY"
          + "  CASE WHEN p.quantity > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC")
  Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

the code refuses to be compiled. On the snippet above, I specifically excluded the sorting of `updatedAt` field as I expect that parameter to be supplied to `Sort` class, which is part of `Pageable` interface.

Would anyone be able to give me any clue/pointer on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like this can be achieved in a much simpler way, there is no need to use subqueries and then merge them. The following suffice:

```java
  @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p ORDER BY CASE WHEN p.quantity > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END")
  Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The ordering by `updatedAt` is taken care of by `Sort` class in `Pageable`.